# Handling Camunda Error Event with External Tasks

Tags: bpmn, camunda

Can we handle Error Event by using External tasks?
as third party program used to solve or log errors raised from error event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the failure rest API call to report a failure to execute an external task back to Camunda.

Documented here [Handle External Task Failure](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.4/reference/rest/external-task/post-failure/)